# Slider is repeating slides - how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, netsuite

I have been struggling to get a slider to work in Netsuite to no avail. I have tried building new sliders using different methods at least 4 different times with no success. Everything works when I use testers, but when I put them on Netsuite, *something* always manages to go wrong. So, I've gone back to the original code and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the slider repeats the first slide. The slider will proceed normally and then adds a slide that is identical to the first slide. 
My goal is to have the slider work in the same way but not repeat the first slide.

```
    <section class="home-slider" data-cms-area="home_content_slider" data-cms-area-filters="path" data-slider-big>


<div id="cms-home-content" class="cms-home-content">
<a href="/SLC-Suppy-Guide-2017">
<img src="/assets/SLC_2017_SupplyGuide_Banner.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>

<div id="cms-home-content" class="cms-home-content">
<a href="/Leather/Exotics">
<img src="/assets/SLC_VegTan_Kangaroo_Banner.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>

<div id="cms-home-content" class="cms-home-content">
<a href="/Leather/Furs">
<img src="/assets/SLC_Foxtail_Banner.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>

<div id="cms-home-content" class="cms-home-content">
<a href="/Leather/Chap-Bag-Upholstery">
<img src="/assets/SLC_PLUME_banner.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>


<div id="cms-home-content" class="cms-home-content">
<a href="/Field-Drab-Oil-Tan">
<img src="/assets/SLC_FieldDrab_OilTan_banner.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.home-slider').bxSlider({
    nextText: '<a class="home-gallery-next-icon"></a>'
    , prevText: '<a class="home-gallery-prev-icon"></a>'
    , slideMargin: 0
    , auto: true
    , pause: 5000
    , useCSS: true
    , slideWidth: '1170'
    , maxSlides:1
    });

</script>
```

I'm not sure if you'll be able to replicate the problem without Netsuite. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No way for us to really replicate this issue.  One problem is that you're missing a closing `</section>` tag.  Does the slider show the 1st slide twice in a row, or is the second time after other slides?  If you swap the order of the slides, is it the new first slide that gets repeated, or is it still the `SLC-Suppy-Guide-2017` slide?

Comment: It shows the first slide at the end of the slideshow. So, if I have four slides, it automatically adds a fifth that is identical to the first slide. It plays slide five and right after, it shows slide one. It is always whichever slide is first.

Comment: See my answer below, and let me know if you still have the same problem after removing the duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting these issues:

- Your `<div>` elements all have the same IDs; change them so they are unique (i.e. `cms-home-content1`, `cms-home-content2`, etc.)
- Add a closing `</section>` tag

Does the problem persist?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are. I tried removing the DIVs altogether because it didn't seem that they were necessary and it seemed to have no effect. The closing tag also didn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: WAIT WAIT I put the </section> tag in the wrong spot! Moving it above the Java seems to have fixed it!! I can't believe the solution was that simple. Thank you so much!